# Perform cleanup actions after Exception

Tags: c#, exception, log4net

A process runs that parses many xml files, and within each file there are many nodes that represent work to be done.

Currently, errors that occur are logged to log4net one at a time, logging to a file once per error, and also generating an email once per error. This is not ideal, so I'm working to roll up all the errors that occur during one parsing session so they can be sent as a single email. For example, let's say the creator of the files accidentally left a crucial field out of each work node. Instead of 4,000 emails, I'd like to send a single email with 4,000 results, plus a summary at the top saying "4,000 field missing errors" and so on.

The trick comes when dealing with exceptions, because I don't know in advance what exception will occur. So, the previous state of the system worked well for tolerating exceptions because it flushed its knowledge as soon as it acquired it (sent an email, for example). But now I'm seeing that waiting until the end to send the email risks not sending an email at all. Let's say the nature of a repeating error is such that eventually it causes a system-level exception. By losing any error reporting at all, I never get the information on the repeating error that (almost certainly) led up to the big crash.

How can I get the best of both worlds, where logging is saved until the end, but whatever work is done and whatever information is collected has a decent chance of being logged even if an error occurs?

One thought I had was sending log information to a custom log4net appender that does caching or batching, and thus allows modification of the log message over time until it is finally triggered to be sent/logged (perhaps accepts individual items and a lambda that it executes at the end to assemble those items into a loggable result). Then, in my application:

```
var loggingContext = CreateNewLoggingContext();
try {
   // Note: all reasonable and known or handleable exceptions will be
   // caught from within this message. We're talking unforeseen or
   // difficult to handle errors, here.
   ParseAndProcessABunchOfFiles(loggingContext);
   // within this method repeatedly use loggingContext.Push("error id", "error message");
}
catch (Exception e) {
   loggingContext.Push("System-level exception", e);
   loggingContext.Flush();
   throw;
}
loggingContext.Flush();
```

But I am not particularly excited about catching every exception. An `OutOfMemoryException` is going to make it pretty hard to do an operation such as logging that might require even *more* memory. Or a disk full exception is going to make it hard to add to the log file on disk (though it would be grand if it still tried to run its email result and perhaps also log to the database).

How can I achieve these goals in a reasonable way?

**UPDATE**

Part of what's troubling me is distinguishing at each level in the call stack what is a recoverable error and what's one that should terminate the whole process. I guess what I have to do is simply catch the ones I can think of and reasonably expect, then as other exceptions show up, add specific handling for them.

Comment: Why do you want to keep all the logging info in the memory? Why not  just use log4net capabilities and save the info to a file or a db?

Comment: Run the app as a windows service if you want to catch things like out of memory or disk space. These kinds of failures should be logged as window events, and handled by the OS in an appropriate way.

Comment: have you considered try...catch...finally? And put whatever cleanup in the finally?

Comment: @Gread of course I've considered try/catch/finally. Are you saying that it's that simple? I can trust my logs to get written correctly even after a fatal error?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia It is a windows service already. How does that help me solve the problem?

Comment: @DanielS and how does simply logging get me the roll up capabilities I spelled out as wanting in my question?